# how to add values from a database output to the data field in Line Chart of Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to add the values which I get from a database.These values from the database are stored in a separate array.So how should I write the code so that I can put values in the **data** field which can then be plotted. Also I want to change the **labels** array to the values contained in a separate array.

```
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="1000" height="400" style="border:2px solid green"></canvas>

<script>

var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","August"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,0,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [0,9,0,8,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [100,100,100,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Take look at the article about preprocessign data http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Answer (score 1):

**First thing first** 
You need to replace data : [0,9,0,8,56,55,40] with data : [data_array1]

data_array1 is an data_string came from database, all you need to do is just convert that data array into highchart acceptable format. For that you need to fetch the data from database, implode it with comma(,), that it will return a string which will be something like this 0,9,0,8,56,55,40
Just echo it data : [data_array1]